# Wpf Control from Library not loaded correctly when using in plugin architecture

Tags: wpf

I have a WPF app that loads some plugins during runtime using reflection. I created a new plugin that uses the [MultiSelectTreeView](https://github.com/dg9ngf/MultiSelectTreeView) library. If I show a window now through the plugin using this lib, I get lots of Binding Errors:

> System.Windows.Data Warning: 40 : BindingExpression path error: '(Controls:MultiSelectTreeView.HoverHighlighting)' property not found on 'object' ''MultiSelectTreeView' (Name='')'. BindingExpression:Path=(Controls:MultiSelectTreeView.HoverHighlighting); DataItem='MultiSelectTreeView' (Name=''); target element is 'MultiSelectTreeViewItem' (Name=''); target property is 'HoverHighlighting' (type 'Boolean')
>   System.Windows.Data Warning: 40 : BindingExpression path error: '(Controls:MultiSelectTreeView.ItemIndent)' property not found on 'object' ''MultiSelectTreeView' (Name='')'. BindingExpression:Path=(Controls:MultiSelectTreeView.ItemIndent); DataItem='MultiSelectTreeView' (Name=''); target element is 'MultiSelectTreeViewItem' (Name=''); target property is 'ItemIndent' (type 'Int32')
>   System.Windows.Data Warning: 40 : BindingExpression path error: '(Controls:MultiSelectTreeView.IsKeyboardMode)' property not found on 'object' ''MultiSelectTreeView' (Name='')'. BindingExpression:Path=(Controls:MultiSelectTreeView.IsKeyboardMode); DataItem='MultiSelectTreeView' (Name=''); target element is 'MultiSelectTreeViewItem' (Name=''); target property is 'IsKeyboardMode' (type 'Boolean')

One Error for each Item in the Tree. The tree still works but it is slow as hell.

Funny thing is, if I also add the library to the main app and show a window from the main app using a tree *before* opening the window from the plugin, no errors occur any more and everything works as expected in the first place.

To me this seems like a weird WPF resource loading thing. Can anyone help me as I am totally clueless on what to do.

Answer (score 0):

If you know the [pack URI](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/aa970069(v=vs.100).aspx) of the tree view library's resource file(s) then try merging it into the application's resource dictionary:-

```
var uri = new Uri("pack://application:,,,/The.Assembly.Name;component/blah/blah.xaml", UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute);

Application.Current.Resources.MergedDictionaries.Add(new ResourceDictionary { Source = uri });
```

I guess you'll want to do this from within your plugin, assuming you have some kind of 'initialisation' method that gets called after the plugin has been loaded.